# Azure Function Crash w/ Relation to IBM.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-functions, db2, w3wp

For awhile I've been experiencing an issue in Azure Functions where the app crashes without logs and will not restart on it's own. By looking at the `eventlog.xml` I've been able to track down an `AggregateException` stemming from some `NullReferenceException` in a GRPC startup.

```
Application: w3wp.exe CoreCLR Version: 6.0.2623.60508 .NET Version: 6.0.26 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)) ---> 
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) ---> 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Grpc.AspNetCoreGrpcServer.ShutdownAsync() in /_/src/WebJobs.Script.Grpc/Server/AspNetCoreGrpcServer.cs:line 60 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcInitializationService.OuterStopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/WebJobs.Script/Workers/Rpc/RpcInitializationService.cs:line 77 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.HostedServiceManager.StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/WebJobs.Script/HostedServiceManager.cs:line 29 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostedServiceExecutor.ExecuteAsync(Func`2 callback, Boolean throwOnFirstFailure) 
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostedServiceExecutor.ExecuteAsync(Func`2 callback, Boolean throwOnFirstFailure) 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.WaitForTokenShutdownAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String startupMessage) 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String startupMessage) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) 
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait() 
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Program.Main(String[] args) in /_/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/Program.cs:line 30
```

I believe that the cause is something within the `IBM.EntityFrameworkCore` package `v6.0.0.300` targeting DB2 AS400, because this does not happen anywhere else that I have similar setups for SQL Server. This has not been reproducible, it just happens sometimes. Has anyone run into this issue, or know of any work arounds?

Have currently reached out to Microsoft Support without much luck, when I thought this was an IIS issue. Have not tried much as the logs around this are few and far between, and seems to be some issue at a lower level. I did see a work around that I have yet to try where someone with a smiliar `w3wp.exe` exception wrapped their `Startup` in try/catch and exited with `-1` to get the server to restart after a fail. Might give that a go, but would like to get to the bottom of this problem.

Expectation is that the app runs without randomly dying and not restarting itself after this failure.

Comment: Basic problem determination needed. You have to link the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" to something in IBM.EntityFramework, else the fault lies elsewhere.  Does the symptom happen on any similar non-prod environments? Anything in the i-series diagnostics corresponding to the timestamp of the unhandled-exception?  Does the symptom happen when tracing IBM.EntityFrameworkCore? Any detectable patterns to symptom timestamps? Is your app capable of logging exceptions/errors/warnings from IBM.EntityFrameworkCore?

Comment: Thanks for coming in @mao, yes the fault lies in both prod and non-prod environments of this app. I need to see about the EntityFrameworkCore logging, I know standard EntityFrameworkCore does but this may be different. We have not been able to reproduce this issue, it just happens on occasion